# Scanning with the Canon mp620 with error code U163

Tags: printer, scanner, canon-pixma

I have a [Canon Pixma MP620](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&fcategoryid=116&modelid=17406) with an empty black ink cartridge.  This particular printer is an "all-in-one" and can scan documents.  However, every time I turn the printer on, the LCD shows the following error message:

> U163
>   The following ink has run out.  Replace the ink tank.  [image of ink cartridge with "`bk`" written at the top]

I can't afford a new cartridge right now, but I would still like to use the built-in scanner.  However, I can't get rid of the "U163" error message.  Therefore, I cannot use the printer user interface to actually scan a document.

How do I bypass this error message & use the scanner?  I've pressed each button on the printer to no avail.

Comment: Related: http://www.refreshcartridges.co.uk/igloo/clearing-canon-pixma-check-ink-error-message-u162-u163/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think I've found a solution!  Fat-finger both the "STOP and "BACK" buttons at the same time.  This seems to kick you out to the main menu.

Sorry for prematurely asking a question!

Comment: This answer also worked for me on an mx882.

Comment: Also worked on the mp970 !! LIFESAVER

Answer (score 18):

Hold down the stop button for 5 seconds.

This will also work on the MX870, MX882 models.

Comment: Brilliant! This fixed it for my canon pixma mp510.

Comment: Worked great on my Canon Pixma MX892 as well. Thanks for this!

Comment: Also works on MP600.

Comment: Also works on MP630.

Answer (score 2):

I got my MX882 back to working by pressing stop and holding it for 5 seconds. I got another error shortly after but then I pressed back and okay at the same time to get it working again. Hope this helps.

Comment: But the question asks about MB620.

Comment: Used this on my mp620.