# Is there a way to bypass U053 check ink error message on Canon MX410 printer?

Tags: printer, canon-pixma

**Context**:

I am trying to use the scanner on an old-ish Canon MX 410 printer. I lost the black cartridge. (I am currently using a laser printer for printing. So buying another cartridge is not a real option for me.)

**Question**:

The printer is stuck on the [error message U053](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART114257). Not even the stop button works. Is there a way to bypass this error message without purchasing a LINE cartridge? All I need is the scanner part of the printer.

---

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/106939/295139) provides a solution for MP 620 but doesn't work for my MX 410. Is there a different key combination that may clear the error prompt? I imagine a maintenance personnel has to have a way to bypass this lock that is probably designed to stonewall consumers?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some workarounds that worked for some Canon models in the past:

- Press and hold down **Stop/Reset** button for 5-10 seconds until the error message disappears.
- Press and hold down **Resume/Cancel** button for 5-10 seconds until the error message disappears.
- Press **Resume/Cancel** button once.
- Press the **Start** button once. Then press the **BLACK** button for error message related to the black cartridge or press **COLOR** button for the error message related to the color cartridge.

Comment: Thanks for the list. I tried them all. None worked.